# Followed CodePipeline instructions for S3 website and yaml file is missing

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline for a simple S3 bucket used as a website. It is to respond to changes in github and then build/deploy to the S3 bucket. I followed the simple instructions found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automate-static-website-deployment-to-amazon-s3.html) and in multiple other places.

When I finished this, I ran the pipeline and got the error below concerning a yaml file as part of the build process in CodeBuild. There is literally no discussion of a yaml file in any tutorial that I have read on how to do this.

```
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:27 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:28 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:29 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:29 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/srcXXXXX/src
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:31 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/01/16 19:09:31 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: YAML file does not exist
```

Is this telling me that pulling the code from github didn't work or is it telling me that there was no yaml file in the download?

Answer (score 0):

The Codebuild is expecting a `buildspec.yml` file as part of your source code which codepipeline downloaded from github and sent to CodeBuild. If you are using S3 bucket to host a static website, you can skip the build stage. You need to have a github source and s3 deploy action to move static HTML, CSS files from github to s3. No need for a Build stage.

If there is infact a build required (like a react application), you need to add a `buildspec.yml` file to the root of your github source. The `buildspec.yml` reference is present [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax). A sample buildspec for a create-react-app website looks like below

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build

artifacts: 
  files: 
    - 'build/**/*'
```

Comment: That code is part of my CloudFormation file

Comment: can you share the Cloudformation snippet of the CodeBuild resource ?